# ¿Cómo se escribe el @ en git bash?

Tags: git-bash

Quiero conectarme por ssh a través de git bash, pero cuando intento escribir el @ con los comandos que siempre uso, no me imprime.

Para poder utilizar el @ tengo que escribirlo en otro lado y pegarlo en git bash.

Si alguien me podría indicar que comandos usa se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Intenta teclear `reset` en la terminal de `git` bash y ver si después ya te deja

Comment: simplemente escribo reset?

Comment: Sí, y pulsas intro. Eso "reinicia" el emulador de terminal  (sin afectar a git) que pudieran estar causando algún problema.

Comment: También pudiera ser que **en esa terminal solamente** el mapa de teclado no sea el español, sino el inglés (mientras que en el resto de windows tengas otro). Mira en la barra de estado de windows a ver si tienes las letras ESP, o ENG según el teclado elegido. Pinchando en esas letras puedes cambiar de uno a otro.

Answer (score 2):

Para futuras consultas, no tiene nada que ver con que tu teclado o idioma este desconfigurado, es simplemente la configuracion de la propia terminal git bash, no se en los otros OS pero en windows debes darle con click derecho al tope de la consola git bash (la linea donde estan los botones de maximizar, minimizar y cerrar), luego escoges la opcion '**options**', te vas a la opcion '**keys**' y activas la casilla en el apartado 'keyboards features' que dice '**Ctrl+LeftAlt is AltGr**' (que es como yo normalmente uso el arroba) y listo, deberian poder escribir el @ como siempre, lo digo porque tampoco podia escribirlo y asi lo solucione, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que tengas el teclado en español y estés usando un teclado inglés o viceversa.

Esto suele pasar y los atajos de teclas ya no funcionan como antes lo hacían.

Comment: Si, pero como digo yo puedo escribir perfectamente el @, prueba de ello es que lo estoy escribiendo ahorita. Pero en Git Bash no sé por qué no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

si tenes teclado con pad numerico, proba con la combinacion 'Alt'+'6'+'4' y eso tendria que funcionar, no hace falta cambiar el idioma del teclado.
En mi caso, apretando las teclas con los numeros debajo de las teclas de funcion no me funciona, pero con el pad si.